# Performance using async rest services

Tags: java, performance, rest, jakarta-ee, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand the JAXRS 2.0 async cabilities so I am using Jersey 2.1 and Glassfish 4 in order to run a REST service that has a thread sleep in the payload.

Using

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ManagedAsync
public void getExamples(@PathParam("value") final Integer value,
        @Suspended final AsyncResponse res) {
    // This executes the method by a separated thread
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    res.resume((Integer) value * 2);
}
```

and

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Integer getExamples(@PathParam("value") final Integer value) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (Integer) value * 2;
}
```

with this web.xml

```
<display-name>Jersey2 Example</display-name>
<description>
    An example async Java REST API using Jersey 2
</description>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey2 REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.jersey.test.ExampleApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey2 REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I expect to observe a significant difference on request/sec performance.

However I get exactly the same performance, and I cannot figure why.

Can you give me some hints in what's happening?

Comment: "I expect to observe a significant difference on request/sec performance." What *exactly* are you measuring here?

Comment: Nothig there ... i later use external process with gatling to load test the system. I configure a 5 sec duration test with 10 clients sending requests. Then i see both implementations have almost exactly the same results in all parameters (response time, request/sec, ...)

Comment: You may only see a large performance difference if running with a cpu-load of near 100% AND a significant difference in cpu cycles spent per sync/async-request. Which is unlikely. Async processing only has the advantage of less threads, thus less (stack-)memory used. And even this advantage is nil due to this feature in jersey: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2477